# Why does a 'for' loop in python change unreferenced lists?

Tags: python, list, variables, for-loop, scope

I'm working on a py script which reads in lines from a csv file, manipulates them, and puts them back out. So far I have the csv to list conversion working.

The problem I am having is when I iterate over the temporary lists, the for loops change ALL the temp lists, instead of just the one I want. Here is a simple example of what I'm trying to say.

```
>>> l = [['hi', 'ho'],['no', 'go']]
>>> t = []
>>> y = []
>>> 
>>> for row in l:
...     row[0] = '123'
...     y.append(row)
...     t.append(row)
... 
>>> y
[['123', 'ho'], ['123', 'go']]
>>> t
[['123', 'ho'], ['123', 'go']]
```

So the above is straightforward (hopefully). (Let's assume I want to do other things besides just copy the list l. Just wanted to keep it simple).

But now here is the part I don't get.

```
>>> z = []
>>> for row in y:
...     row[0] = 'xxxx'
...     z.append(row)
... 
>>> z
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['xxxx', 'go']]
>>> t
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['xxxx', 'go']]
>>> y
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['xxxx', 'go']]
```

When I want to modify the first part in the sub-lists, and save it to a new list 'z', it modifies list t as well!

***What's going on here?*** Are z, y and t pointing to the same memory location?

Also, what's happening here?:

```
>>> for rowx in y:
...     rowx[0] = 'x55x'
...     z.append(rowx)
... 
>>> z
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['x55x', 'go'], ['x55x', 'go'], ['x55x', 'go']]
>>> t
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['x55x', 'go']]
>>> y
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['x55x', 'go']]
```

Similar to the above question, why are y and t getting changed?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your three lists are different, but there are only two elements shared between them:

```
>>> y[0] is t[0] is z[0]
True
>>> y[1] is t[1] is z[1]
True
```

If the `is` operator tells you that your references point to the same object, then changes to the object will appear no matter which reference you use.

To avoid this, use the [copy](http://docs.python.org/library/copy.html) module if you want a copy of the elements:

```
>>> import copy
>>> a = copy.deepcopy(y)
>>> a
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['xxxx', 'go']]
>>> a[0] is y[0]
False
>>> a[0][0] = 'copy!'
>>> y
[['xxxx', 'ho'], ['xxxx', 'go']]
```

Comment: For a shallow copy of lists, you can use `y[:]`

Comment: Thanks jleedev! While [:] answered and solved my question, so does your copy.deepcopy solution, which is what I had to do in my script since a shallow copy wasn't enough (apparently). You solved my problem! :)

Comment: @Raytheon The `[:]` slice, a simple `for` loop, and a shallow copy all have exactly the same effect.

Comment: I would think so too, but for some reason when I implemented it my script it still didn't work. It wasn't until I tried your copy solution that the script worked. It's definitely some error on my part, probably due to the csv or the haste that went into creating the script itself.

Answer (score 7):

Python has nothing *but* references. `row` is a reference to the actual element within `l` or `y`. Mutating `row` mutates that element, and adding it to another object adds the original element.

Comment: Use `row[:]` to make a copy of `row`.

Comment: @katrielalex: Can I upvote you, like, 100 times? I've run into the OP's issue with list references and could not for the life of me figure out how to copy a list instead of copying the reference.  Do all list slices return a copy instead of a reference like this?

Comment: @DGH: For `list`, yes. A shallow copy though.

Comment: Thanks Ignacio for that. I can 'see' in my head now how these list references work. And thanks katrielalex for that solution!

Answer (score 0):

"Are z, y and t pointing to the same memory location?"

No, but z[0], y[0] and t[0] are (although don't call it memory locations, this is not C). You are appending the same list `['hi', 'ho']` to both z, y and t. So it's the same list. If you don't want it to be the same list, you have to make a copy first.